# How to fetch an API in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to fetch this API dataset https://kimiquotes.herokuapp.com/quotes in react. I want to allow the user to search from the API using the id. whenever the user clicks on the search button I want to change the color of the search button. after the user enters the id and clicks the search button I want to fetch the dataset and display it in a li list I want to display the id, quotes, and year. Here is the code that I have right now.

```
import "mvp.css";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { Input } from "semantic-ui-react";

function City() {
  const [APIData, setAPIData] = useState([]);
  const [filteredResults, setFilteredResults] = useState([]);
  const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState("");
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(`https://kimiquotes.herokuapp.com/quotes`).then((response) => {
      setAPIData(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  const searchItems = (searchValue) => {
    setSearchInput(searchValue);
    if (searchInput !== "") {
      const filteredData = APIData.filter((item) => {
        return Object.values(item).join("").toLowerCase().includes(searchInput);
      });
      setFilteredResults(filteredData);
    } else {
      setFilteredResults(APIData);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div style={{ padding: 20 }}>
      <Input
        style={{ backgroundColor: "DodgerBlue" }}
        icon="search"
        placeholder="Search for 2008, 2012 or 2013 "
        onChange={(e) => searchItems(e.target.value)}
      />
      <div itemsPerRow={3} style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
        {searchInput.length > 1
          ? filteredResults.map((item) => {
              const { id, quote, year } = item;
              return (
                <div>
                  <div>
                    <h1>ID: {id}</h1>
                    <li>QUOTE: {quote}</li>
                    <li>YEAR: {year}</li>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            })
          : APIData.map(() => {
              return <h1></h1>;
            })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default function App() {
  return <City />;
}
```

Comment: Hey, do you want to make sure that if your data is filtered correctly or not?

Answer (score 0):

Hey @sisii you ask so many question in a post. But trying my best to answer you..
question to answer first=>

```
if (searchInput !== null||undefined) {
      const filteredData = APIData.filter((item) => {
        return item && item?.year.includes(searchInput);
      });
      setFilteredResults(filteredData);
    } else {
      setFilteredResults(APIData);
    }
```

as i see you ask user to pass number so you don't need to convert string to lowercase or uppercase..
Question to answer second=>

```
  <Input
    type="number"
    style={{ backgroundColor: "DodgerBlue" }}
    icon="search"
    onClick={()=>setChangeColor(!changeColor)}
    placeholder="Search for 2008, 2012 or 2013 "
    onChange={(e) => searchItems(e.target.value)}
  />
```

This statement create true and false logic in the state and you just need to pass style conditionally..

Question to answer three-

```
{searchInput.length > 1
          ? filteredResults.map((item,index) => {
              const { id, quote, year } = item;
              return (
                <div key={index}>
                  <table>
                    <tr>
                    <th>ID: {id}</th>
                    <td>QUOTE: {quote}</td>
                    <td>YEAR: {year}</td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div>
              );
            })
          : APIData.map(() => {
              return <h1></h1>;
            })}
```

make these changes to your code, you got what you want, if you still facing issue lemme know. I will help you more.
Thanks